# How to store the GCM push notification message into sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on **GCM**. Everything is okay and I have implemented the GCM successfully and it is working. But I need to save the message into a database table. But when I implemented the below database manipulation code, the GCM stopped working as well as database. No error is shown on log also.

```
   @Override
        protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
            message = (String) intent.getExtras().getCharSequence("hello");
            displayMessage(context, message);
                /* database manipulation */
                String dbName = new String("GCM");
        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(dbName, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String tableName = new String("newsTable");
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(message) VALUES(" + message + ");");                       
                db.close();
                /* database manipulation ends */
            generateNotification(context, message);
        }
```

Again, when I removed the database code snippet, the GCM worked well. 
I made sure that, the database and table is already exist. Is my database manipulation code wrong? if yes, what's the actual way t do so ?

Comment: check my answer and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

Try this way..

Create new **DatabaseHelper  class** that will create and insert message into **sqlite database**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GCM";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "newsTable";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
            + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MESSAGE STRING)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void insertMsg(String msg) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put("MESSAGE", msg);

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

    db.close();

  }
 }
```

**GCM SERVICE**

```
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
        message = (String) intent.getExtras().getCharSequence("hello");
        displayMessage(context, message);

        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        db.insertMsg(message);
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }
```

Always make the code clean, so that it looks easy..

Happy coding :)